# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ in retrofit

Tags: json, retrofit

I am trying to insert data to MySQL from my Android apps using Retrofit. The data is inserting successfully but giving this error. How can I solve this?

My JSON format is

```
{
"error": false,
"message": "Book Issued Successfully"
}
```

I tried to use this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder() .setLenient() .create();
```

But this gives another error:

> “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1”

My database table look like this

[image]

Comment: There is only one explanations: this is not sent as valid `JSON` payload. Probably it is sent as `text/plain` or something like that. Could you post detailed logs with headers? [Retrofit 2 — Log Requests and Responses](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses)

Comment: There is something wrong in my return JSON format which i find after using logging interceptor. Thanks for your reply @MichałZiober